# Do not allow DHCP to assign reserved IPs

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

I have EdgeRouter X with a Linux (EdgeOS) on board, so when I created a new DHCP server for VLAN I have reserved (mapped an IP with a MAC address) a several IPs for my devices to be able to bypass Firewall rules and make adjustments to the configuration; for everyone else, who is trying to connect to the router, firewall just drop a connection. But I'm still able to connect to the router using other devices by manually entering the reserved IP. Is there a way to forbid the router to assign a reserved IP to devices which MAC address does not match a mapped one?

Answer (score 0):

When you manually assign the IP address on a device you are not using DHCP and since you are basing your firewall rules on the devices IP address any device that is manually assigned an address in your rule will be allowed to use it. If you want to create firewall rules for specific devices you should make them based on MAC address instead. This link may help you out.
https://community.ubnt.com/t5/EdgeMAX/Mac-filtering-list/td-p/498197

Comment: Well, there are ways to change MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP does not inherently perform security. The closes thing would be duplicate IP address avoidance.  All networks have the possibility of someone manually configuring a static IP address on their device that is in use already for some other authorized purpose.  The best way to know this is happening is to already have your device using that IP address. This will allow you to see a duplicate IP address warning to know someone is using the wrong address.

With that being said, your EdgeOS may have security features that can identify an incorrect MAC address associated with a reserved IP address and notify you are possibly block connections from it.  However, unless your EdgeOS is tightly integrated with your networks switch and has the ability to shutdown the switch port, then it won't be possible to actually stop the device from using the reserved IP address without authorization.

Comment: The AP uses that VLAN so there is no shut down the switch port.